# Javascript: Is there a keyword for referring to the current node in an object?

Tags: javascript, object, this

Consider the following code:

```
function Animal(){
  this.type = "dog";
  this.color = {
                 stomach: "white",
                 paws: "brown",
                 face: function(){
                   if(this.color.stomach === "white"){
                      return "red";
                   }else{
                      return "blue";
                   }
                 }
}
```

This strangely colored dog has a face color that depends on the color of his stomach. I'm wondering if there is a more syntactically simple way of writing the "this.color.stomach" part. I.e., "this" refers to the main Animal object. Is there a similar keyword that refers to the parent object in which that keyword is called? For example, since I'm already inside Animal.color, rather than having to repeat that part to get at its stomach color (Animal.color.stomach), is there a way to directly reference the color property, so that it would be like "parent.stomach" where "parent" refers to whatever property it's being called within--in this case, Animal.color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running your code? Because `this` actually *does* refer to the `color` and not the `Animal` object.

This is how it works: `this` refers to whatever object the function was called upon, and under normal circumstances, your `face` function would be called as `someAnimal.color.face()` -- in this case, `this` already refers to the `color` object, so `this.color` would be an error while `this.stomach` would actually work.

Comment: Rats. I was about to say the same.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that's how it should work. My problem was in how I was testing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Color(data) {
    this.stomach = data.stomach;
    this.face = data.face;
}

function Animal() {
    var self = this; // self now refers to the animal
    this.type = "Dog";
    this.color = new Color({
        face: function() {
            // in the "face" function, "this" refers to the color
            if (this.stomach === "white") { // color's stomach
                return "red";
            } else if (self.type === "Dog") { // animal's type
                return "Blue";
            }
        }
   });
}
```